# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException while integrating the Flutter module with native Android

Tags: android, flutter

I have created the simple flutter module for triggerring the camera using `platformMethodChannel`. It is working fine, but while integrating this module(.aar) with another native android app giving the below error,

*[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method takePhoto on channel heartbeat.fritz.ai/native)
#0 MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294:7)

#1      _MyStatefulWidgetState._managePower (package:flutterdemo/main.dart:44:7)*

### Flutter code

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  static const platformMethodChannel =
  MethodChannel('heartbeat.fritz.ai/native');
  String nativeMessage = '';

  Future<Null> _managePower() async {
    String _message;
    try {
      final String result =
      await platformMethodChannel.invokeMethod('takePhoto');
      debugPrint("photo--$result");
      _message = result;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      _message = "Can't do native stuff ${e.message}.";
    }
    setState(() {
      nativeMessage = _message;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.volume_up),
          tooltip: 'Increase volume by 10',
          onPressed: _managePower,
        ),
        Text('Volume : $nativeMessage'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

### Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "heartbeat.fritz.ai/native";
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
                    if (call.method.equals("takePhoto")) {
                        readyCamera();
                    }

                });
    }
    public void readyCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have u tried uninstall app -> flutter clean -> run

Comment: @Naveen Yes. But getting same issue

Comment: Have u checked the permissions bro ? like mentioned here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: @naveen,  I have fixed by creating the flutter as module and integrated with existing android project. It`s working fine but my requiement is, how do we disribute this as a library(.aar) to integrate with third party android app. Can you please suggest the approach?

Comment: @vishu how resolve with creating flutter module i am getting missingpluginexception

Comment: I am not able to solve this issue ive created a flutter project first then exported its code to separate flutter module the java files are missing while integrating flutter aar app is working fine in debug mode and the UI is visible after integrating flutter aar but the method channel is not working